# ¿Como mandar mail usando php desde localhost usando Mamp en mac...?

Tags: php

Estoy usando la funcion mail pero no se como usarlo o si debo activar algo y como seria ya en el caso de que este en un servidor real

Comment: la respuesta a esta pregunta es el help de la función mail de PHP...

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la clase phpmailer.php, te paso un trozo de código que uso para enviar a traves de gmail:

```
require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer(true); 
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Mailer = "sendmail";
//-GMAIL
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl"; 
$mail->Host = "smtp.googlemail.com";
$mail->Port = 465; 
$mail->Username = "usuario@gmail.com"; 
$mail->Password = "laclave";
$mail->SetFrom('remitente@gmail.com', 'NombreRemitente');

$mail->MsgHTML($cuerpomail);
$mail->AddAddress("destinatario@gmail.com", "Destinatario"); 
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Send();
$mail->ClearAddresses(); 
$mail->ClearAttachments();
```

Comment: Correcto, solo añadir que si quieres hacerlo desde php puro con la funcion mail, debes configurar config.php. Pero repito que lo mejor es lo que te sugiere el compañero.